# Hashing - put(self, key) function

Tags: python, hash

Can anyone help me fix my put function for inserting a value into the hash table, it's returning hash table full of None's

```
class BasicHashTable:
    def __init__(self,size=7):
        self.size = size
        self.slots = [None] * self.size

    def hash_function(self, key):
        return key%len(self.slots)

    def rehash(self, old_pos):
        return (old_pos + 1) % self.size

    def put(self, key):
        hash_value = key%len(self.slots)    
        probe_seq=[]     
        insert_pos=hash_value     
        probe_seq+=[insert_pos]     
        probes=1     
        while(self.slots[insert_pos]!=None):         
            probes+=1         
            insert_pos=(insert_pos+1)%len(self.slots)         
            probe_seq+=[insert_pos]     
            self.slots[insert_pos]=key     
        return insert_pos
```

Comment: And your question is? Please provide input, expected output and possible error messages.

Comment: Question is to add the def put function for inserting a value into the hash table, the error I'm getting is the hash table is full of "None"